# wp cron job fires at every second or so, if callback is wrapped with DOING_CRON check it never fires at all

Tags: hooks, wp-cron, cron, options, wp-remote-request

I am a bit lost while dealing with a open source plugin implementing wp cron.

You can read about the problem on github https://github.com/nekojira/wp-currencies/issues/6#issuecomment-116735909 - I will summarise it also here. Unfortunately there's a bit of code involved to paste it on Stack.

I have a method in one class, which makes a remote request and updates some rows when called: 
https://github.com/nekojira/wp-currencies/blob/master/includes/rates.php#L64

In short:

```
// Rates class
public function update() {
   // do wp_remote_get(), do stuff in db, return response results
}
```

This method is **only** called by "update_currencies" method in a class in my plugin that deals with Cron:
https://github.com/nekojira/wp-currencies/blob/master/includes/cron.php#L41

In short:

```
// Cron class
public function update_currencies() {
    if ( defined( 'DOING_CRON' ) ) {
        do_action( 'wp_currencies_before_update', time() );
        $rates = new Rates();
        $rates->update();
    }
}
```

As you can see it's wrapped with DOING_CRON check... But it seems not to fire, ever. If I remove DOING_CRON it will fire at every second or so.

This last method `update_currencies` it's only used as callback of a wp cron action:
https://github.com/nekojira/wp-currencies/blob/master/includes/cron.php#L29

In short:

```
// Cron class
public function __construct() {
    add_filter( 'cron_schedules', array( $this, 'cron_schedules' ), 10, 1 ) ;
    add_action( 'wp_currencies_update', array( $this, 'update_currencies' ) );
}
```

The action is a wp cron scheduled event, which changes only in two occasions:
1) upon plugin installation & activation:
https://github.com/nekojira/wp-currencies/blob/master/includes/cron.php#L56
2) When options for my specific plugin are saved:
https://github.com/nekojira/wp-currencies/blob/master/includes/settings.php#L211
https://github.com/nekojira/wp-currencies/blob/master/includes/settings.php#L40

In short, this is the action set by the plugin on init:

```
 add_action( 'update_option_wp_currencies_settings', array( $this, 'updated_option' ), 10, 2 );
```

and this is the callback that is fired when updating option `'update_option_wp_currencies_settings'`:

```
public function updated_option( $old_value, $new_value ) {
    // Is there an update?
    if ( $old_value != $new_value ) {
        wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'wp_currencies_update' );
        // Makes sure there's an API key (won't be able to tell if valid, but at least is not empty).
        $api_key = isset( $new_value['api_key'] ) ? $new_value['api_key'] : ( isset( $old_value['api_key'] ) ? $old_value['api_key'] : '' );
        if ( ! empty( $api_key ) ) {
            wp_schedule_event( time(), esc_attr( $new_value['update_interval'] ), 'wp_currencies_update' );
            do_action( 'wp_currencies_rescheduled_update', time(), esc_attr( $new_value['update_interval'] ) );
        }
    }
}
```

The update intervals are set by the user via an option - but I double checked them and the most frequent interval is still 3600 seconds.

I have read both WordPress documentation and looked in Core itself and I am a bit lost as I can't find what's causing the issue... It's a free plugin I made I would like to find a solution.

Comment: Could you, please, post the relevant code in the question itself? It makes easier to have a full view of the context and it makes the question useful in the future even if the external service goes down.

Comment: Have you defined an alternate cron in your wp-config?

Comment: @cybmeta I'll try to edit my question... I thought it was more readable this way

Comment: @BrandtSolovij no apparently that is not the culprit

Comment: edited with code snippets